# Synergy setup on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, synergy, setup

Are there any basic guides on setting up synergy on 2 Windows PC's?

W7 is server, XP is client.

1. I am running a single monitor with multiple video inputs, will this cause any issues when switching between inputs?
2. Do I have to open any ports in the firewalls on each PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found one

http://woikr.com/howto/synergy-share-a-single-mouse-and-keyboard-between-multiple-computers/

Please feel free to answer my other questions.